# How to get Stock price for each day at 15:00 cet? df = web.DataReader('TSLA','google',start,end) can we include time here(15:00 cet)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

How to get Stock price for each day at 15:00 cet?  df = web.DataReader('TSLA','google',start,end) can we include specific time here(15:00 cet) ? 
for example price at this time , each day

2012-10-08 18:15:05', '
2012-10-09 18:15:05',
'2012-10-10 18:15:05', 
'2012-10-11 18:15:05',
  '2012-10-12 18:15:05',

Code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import datetime 
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1,18:15:05)  
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1,18:15:05) 
web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? If so, please show us the code.

Comment: import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1,18:15:05)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1,18:15:05)
web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start, end)

Comment: thanks for your reply . i am really new python . (only couple of hours old ) sorry if the question is too basic .tried looking up but no success

Comment: I never worked with python, sorry :-( (i did but like, only in high school --')
I tried to do a bit of research to help you but i couldn't figure out how to help. Sorry. Maybe try asking on Quora ?